# Not able to get data from Json completely

Tags: android, json, parsing, listview

i am getting JSON data from **http://abinet.org/?json=1** and displaying the titles in a `ListView`. the code is working fine but the problem is, it is skipping few titles in my `ListView` and one title is being repeated.

You can see the json data from url given above by copy paste it in JSON editor online http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
i want titles in the "posts" array to be displayed in `ListView`, however it is being displayed like this:

[image]

if you see the JSON data from the link above, its missing like 3 titles (they should come between the first and second title) and 5th title is being repeated. Dont know why this is happening. What minor adjustments i need to do? Please help me.

this is my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://abinet.org/?json=1";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_POSTS = "posts";
static final String TAG_TITLE = "title";



private ProgressDialog pDialog;
JSONArray contacts = null;
TextView img_url;


ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> contactList;
ListView lv;
LazyAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newslist);

    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    new GetContacts().execute();
}



private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute();
         // Showing progress dialog
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
         pDialog.setCancelable(false);
         pDialog.show();

     }


    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {



        // Making a request to url and getting response

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        // Getting JSON from URL
        JSONObject jsonObj = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


       // if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {


                // Getting JSON Array node
                contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);




                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                  // JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);


                   JSONObject posts = contacts.getJSONObject(i);
                   String title = posts.getString(TAG_TITLE).replace("&#8217;", "'");
                   JSONArray attachment = posts.getJSONArray("attachments");
                     for (int j = 0; j< attachment.length(); j++){
                   JSONObject obj = attachment.getJSONObject(j);
                   JSONObject image = obj.getJSONObject("images");

                   JSONObject image_small = image.getJSONObject("thumbnail");

                   String  imgurl = image_small.getString("url");  


                    HashMap<String, Object> contact = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                    contact.put("image_url", imgurl);

                    contact.put(TAG_TITLE, title);
                    contactList.add(contact);
                     }    

               }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();



        adapter=new LazyAdapter(MainActivity.this, contactList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



   }

 }
```

this is my  JsonParser class (although its not required):

```
public JSONParser() {
}
 public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {
  // Making HTTP request
  try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
 }
  try {
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
       is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
      sb.append(line + "n");
   }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
  }  catch (Exception e) {
   Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }
  // try parse the string to a JSON object
  try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
  } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
 }
 // return JSON String
 return jObj;
}
}
```

and this is adapter class:

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;


public LazyAdapter(Activity a,ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.third_row, null);

    TextView title = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.headline3); // title
    SmartImageView iv =  (SmartImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageicon);


   HashMap<String, Object> song = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    song = data.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText((CharSequence) song.get(MainActivity.TAG_TITLE));

    iv.setImageUrl((String) song.get("image_url"));
  thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
}
```

Please help me. I am stuck at this for more than a week now. I think there is just something to be changed in my `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Could you post the GetContacts Async method? What do you pass into your `onPostExecute`?

Comment: GetContacts Async method is in the first code. In my onPostExecute i just set the adapter. The adapter puts all the titles in the listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the 10 (well today there are 10 ) 'titles' have no 'attachments'. Some have one and some have two. There are only 5 titles wich have one or two images. You only create a new

```
HashMap<String, Object> contact
```

if there are attachments. (The attachment are the images). You should create the 'contact' before you enter the attachments loop. Further you only need one image for each title. You can set the image null if there are no attachments. In getView if the image is null you set some image from your drawable res.

Comment: Damm !! i never noticed there were empty arrays in some of the attachments. now i see the problem.  so now how am i suppose to get the images. The image url is also in the "content" tag of "posts array" but that has more things in it. Is it possible to get only the image url (which is the first line of content) from it?  Btw thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: You just have to do the changes I suggested. It will take you five minutes.

Comment: i cannot set images from drawables. its a news website. The news titles will change daily. i have to get images from the url. those url's which are not given in attachment how am i suppose to do get from content setcion?

Comment: You only set one from drawable if there is no image specified. When attachments.size() == 0. Otherwise you download the specified image as you do now. Then what would you display if there is no image specified? Of course the news changes dayly. Other titles othes images. Everybody knows that.

Comment: there might not be image url in the attachment for some titles but for those titles i can get the image url from the "concent" tag. the content tag also has the image url in it.

Comment: Then please post that piece of code when you are done.

Comment: that is what i am trying to ask. the "content" tag has image url and the description about the news as one single string. how should i extract only the image url from "content"? if you can take a look the the "content" tag.

Comment: There might not always be an img tag with a src of an image in content. So you have to be prepared for the case that there is no image. So first start creating your hashmap for every title. Add the title. Then determine an image url. Maybe the image url stays empty. Does not matter. Add the image url to the map. Then add the map to the array list. Show me how you extract the content of the contact tag.

Comment: hmm.. i might as well ask the website admin to put attachments wherever he hasn't added.

Comment: Good luck. But that's not an alternative. As you refuse work you're fired. As you are not longer working on the project we don't have to discuss a function `getImageUrlFromContent(content)` which works very well here ;-).

Comment: well admin thing dint work out. i have to work on getImageUrlFromContent(content) method. I'll see what i can do.

Comment: i cannot use .subString(startIndex,endIndex); because the endIndex will be different for different posts.

Comment: Both startIndex and endIndex can be different for different posts. Thats why you have to determine them every time. I use substring() too. You are not trying to get the href are you?

Comment: yes exactly ! href has the image url for every post. the startIndex would be same for all posts but not endIndex.

Comment: No not exactly! Do not take href. Take src from img tag. The href might be html. Dont suppose that it is always jpg.

Comment: it is always .jpg. If not from href, then from where am i suppose to get image. nowhere else in the entire post the image url is given.

Comment: Today it is always a jpg yes. But don't count on it. Get it from the img tag src="" attrbute. I said that before.

Comment: ohh yeah . i can take from image src tag.. but then again how should i extract that part of the string from the whole content.

Comment: The href is an attribute of an a tag. That a tag is on an img. The img has a src=. If you do not see it in the first 150 characters then what content did you grab?

Comment: Start with determining startIndex using content.indexOf("src="); then make a substring with length say 200. Does not matter to much.  Your substring now starts with http:// The url ends at the " so determine that index with mysubsting.indexOf("\"");

Comment: k. will try it out in some time.

Comment: done!! its working like a charm now. this is the code i used: String content = posts.getString("content");
int startIndex = content.indexOf("src=")+5;
String substring = content.substring(startIndex, startIndex+200);
int subendIndex = substring.indexOf("\"");
int endIndex = startIndex + subendIndex;
String imageurl = content.substring(startIndex,endIndex);           thanx a lot man! you made my day !!